# significan​t lags in causality test?

Tags: granger-causality

significan​t lags in causality test?
[Cross-posted to R-Sig-Finance]

Hi all,
I have a question regarding Granger causality test.
I have searched on Internet intensively and extensively and have used both the "grangertest" function in lmtest package and the "causality" function in vars package.
If we see that x causes y, is there a way to obtain the significant lags of x which help forecast y?
Thanks!